# My code is not extracting Images from all PDF files

Tags: java, maven, pdf, itext

Kindly help me, my code which extracts images from PDF file, is not extracting images from all PDF files. Although it works good for Some PDF Files. Please help me.
Here is my Code : 
ExtractImages.java

```
package pdttotextconvertor;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;

/**
 * Extracts images from a PDF file.
 */
public class ExtractImages {

    /**
     * PDF to extract images from
     */
    public static final String SOURCE_PDF = "C:/Latest Maven Code/pdttotextconvertor/src/main/resources/LC DPF example 1.pdf";

    /**
     * Parses a PDF and extracts all the images.
     *
     * @param filename the source PDF
     * @param destination the directory to save images
     */
    public void extractImages(String filename, String destination)
            throws IOException, DocumentException {
        System.out.println("Processing PDF at " + filename);
        System.out.println("Saving images to " + destination);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        ImageRenderListener listener = new ImageRenderListener(destination + "/Img%s.%s");
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            parser.processContent(i, listener);
        }
        reader.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param args no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String sourcePDF = SOURCE_PDF;
        String destination = "target/images";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            sourcePDF = args[0];
            if (args.length > 1) {
                destination = args[1];
            }
        }

        new ExtractImages().extractImages(sourcePDF, destination);
    }
}
```

ImageRenderListener.java

```
package scannedPdfConvertor;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Saves images to a directory.
 *
 * @author mnguyen
 */
public class ImageRenderListener implements RenderListener {

    /**
     * The directory path to store images.
     */
    protected String path;

    /**
     * Creates a RenderListener that will look for images.
     */
    public ImageRenderListener(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#beginTextBlock()
     */
    public void beginTextBlock() {
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#endTextBlock()
     */
    public void endTextBlock() {
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#renderImage(
     * com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo)
     */
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        try {
            String filename;
            FileOutputStream os;
            PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
            if (image == null) {
                return;
            }
            filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), image.getFileType());
            System.out.println("Writing image to file: " + filename);
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageRenderListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#renderText(
     * com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo)
     */
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {

    }
}
```

Pdf file link which is not working is http://www.filedropper.com/lcdpfexample23

Please Help Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Share your pdf file. And don't tag your question with pdfbox if your question is about iText.

Comment: Just saying "my code doesn't work sometimes" and posting uncommented code is no good, since you are asking for help. Do you have any ideas where your problem occures? Does your log contain any information?  Does your code finish without errors? And so on

Comment: My guess is that the OP either mistakes vector images for raster images (his code only extracts *Image XObjects*) or he encounters images that are not supported by iText (I'm not sure, but I think that extracting JBIG2 isn't supported; you can convert JBIG2 to PDF with iText, but I don't think there's a way back).

Comment: In particular images with interesting colour spaces are not supported by itext image extraction.

Comment: Here is the Pdf file http://www.filedropper.com/lcdpfexample23 , i am unable to extract image as well as data from this pdf file. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The sample document "LC DPF example 2.3.pdf" shared by the OP neither contains bitmap images nor text. It contains only vector graphics.

E.g. what we read as the letter "P" in "Page 3 of our letter..." in the first line actually is drawn using these (m)ove, (l)ine, (c)urve, close (h), and (f)ill instructions:

```
71.16 804.07 m
71.16 806.83 l
72.12 806.83 l
72.72 806.83 73.2 806.83 73.56 806.83 c
73.8 806.95 74.04 807.07 74.28 807.19 c
74.52 807.43 74.76 807.67 74.88 807.91 c
75 808.27 75.12 808.63 75.12 809 c
75.12 809.59 75 810.07 74.76 810.43 c
74.4 810.79 74.04 811.03 73.68 811.15 c
73.44 811.15 72.84 811.27 72 811.27 c
69.72 811.27 l
69.72 804.07 l
71.16 804.07 l
h
71.88 810.07 m
72.36 810.07 72.72 809.95 72.84 809.95 c
73.08 809.95 73.32 809.83 73.44 809.71 c
73.56 809.47 73.68 809.23 73.68 809 c
73.68 808.75 73.56 808.63 73.56 808.51 c
73.44 808.27 73.2 808.15 73.08 808.15 c
72.84 808.03 72.48 808.03 71.88 808.03 c
71.16 808.03 l
71.16 810.07 l
71.88 810.07 l
h
f
```

Thus, the `RenderListener` interface the OP implements won't find anything (as it only is listens to bitmap images and text).

He could implement `ExtRenderListener` which additionally listens to path creation and rendering instructions. Unfortunately that will only give him the equivalent of the instructions shown above, not an interpretation like "this filled path looks like a letter 'P'".

Thus, he would either have to implement such character path recognition himself or use OCR instead.